# How to extract the model matrix from a Julia GLM object

Tags: julia

I'm playing around with linear regression in **Julia** using the GLM package. I am interested in getting the model matrix out from the **LM** object so I can calculate leverage values (diagonals of the hat matrix), but can't find any function to do this. The equivalent in R is `model.matrix`.

- Any suggestions?

I guess I could just do the regression manually via matrix multiplication, but didn't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured this out, by calling `names(OLS)` on the LM object (which I am calling `OLS`). Then the model matrix can be extracted by `OLS.mm`.

Comment: Please mark this as your answer when you are able to.

Answer (score 0):

If the data you're using is a `DataFrame` you can use the following:

```
using DataFrames, GLM
dat = dataset("car","Vocab")
x = ModelMatrix(ModelFrame(Vocabulary~Year+Sex+Education,dat)).m
```